# Advanced Form Fill that will appear another form fill if right click checkbox

Tags: php, html, css

## What is procedure to make it like this ? please view the link below

1. *Before i right click the checkbox :*
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAr8G.png
2. *After Right click the checkbox :*
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jphe.png

*how can i do like that?

*how can i implement it using radio form fill?

*how can i appear and hide the other form fill?

Comment: With 'right click' do you mean checking the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all take your captcha box into one DIV. for example `<div id="captcha"></div>`.Put your captcha box into this div. Then give the ID property to your checkbox for example, `<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk"/>`.

Then after add following line in the head section.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then put below jquery under the `<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk"/>`

```
<script>
$('#chk').on('click',function(){
if($('#chk').prop('checked'))
{

$('#captcha').hide();
}
else
{
$('#captcha').show();
}
});
</script>
```

Don't forget to change name and all that according to your requirement.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rtvK7/

To do this via radio click on following link for demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/rtvK7/1/

Comment: @Person93 its my pleasure friend.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery toggle for the captcha div you are using, use the jquery event " $('#myform :checkbox').click() " for initiating the toggle, i suppose this will help.